# Download PDF file and save in document directory

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pdf, remote-server

I have the following code that allows me to download a PDF file from a URL, it works correctly:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let _ = DownloadManager.shared.activate()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        DownloadManager.shared.onProgress = { (progress) in
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                self.progressView.progress = progress
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        DownloadManager.shared.onProgress = nil
    }

    @IBAction func startDownload(_ sender: Any) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/KMS-Cryptographic-Details.pdf")!
        let task = DownloadManager.shared.activate().downloadTask(with: url)
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

The file is currently going to: `file:///Users/cybermac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CAEC75D0-423A-4FB2-B0D6-9E7CADB190A1/data/Containers/Data/Application/8B5CBFC8-7058-48DB-A1C4-872302A80610/Library/Caches/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/Downloads/com.example.DownloadTaskExample/CFNetworkDownload_Q7OVlf.tmp`

How do I save it in `/Documents/`?

Something like this: `file:///Users/cybermac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CAEC75D0-423A-4FB2-B0D6-9E7CADB190A1/data/Containers/Data/Application/64370B29-2C01-470F-AE76-17EF1A7BC918/Documents/`

The idea is that the file saved in that directory can be used to read it offline (with PDFKit or webKit). It will only be deleted if the application is deleted.

Comment: check this. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34346220/cant-copy-file-from-bundle-to-documents-directory-in-ios)

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani, your suggestive link is irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to move the file to your custom location after the download. Implement `URLSessionDownloadDelegate` and you will receive the location of your downloaded file.

Delegate method:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL)
```

Code to move the file:

```
do {
    let documentsURL = try
        FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                in: .userDomainMask,
                                appropriateFor: nil,
                                create: false)

    let savedURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("yourCustomName.pdf")
    try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: savedURL)
} catch {
    print ("file error: \(error)")
}
```

To learn more refer to [this repo](https://github.com/skdevil/PrakrstaFileDownloader).

Comment: Sorry to bothering you, reference to your answer. Can I ask one question related to pdf document file?

Comment: @Newbie Yes, what is that?

Comment: First of all thank you. Here is the link of my question. I perfectly downloading pdf files but its not accessible offline mode. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59715589/pdf-file-reading-issue-only-on-offline-mode-swift?noredirect=1#comment105587464_59715589

Answer (score 0):

This snippet was downloaded your Remote PDF from Server and "Save" into your Photo Library

```
   func drawPDFfromURL(url: URL) -> UIImage? {
    guard let document = CGPDFDocument(url as CFURL) else { return nil }
    guard let page = document.page(at: 1) else { return nil }

    let pageRect = page.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: pageRect.size)
    let img = renderer.image { ctx in
        UIColor.white.set()
        ctx.fill(pageRect)

        ctx.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: pageRect.size.height)
        ctx.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

        ctx.cgContext.drawPDFPage(page)
    }

    return img
}
```

## step 2

```
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(drawPDFfromURL(url: url!) ?? UIImage(), nil, nil, nil)
```